# regex for strings with special characters at end

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex for string with 6-12 characters long, start with number, followed by anything and end with non-alpabet and non-number. i have this, but this does not work. Any help here? examples are
`123abc$$`, `2%fat?`, `4ever!@`

```
^[0-9](?=.*)[^a-z0-9]{6,12}$
```

Comment: I've balanced the downvote, because even if the question is very easy, at least the asker has shown his current attempt that need help fixing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a lookahead, because it doesn't consume characters, it just requires the regular expression to be next to that. You also don't need 6-12 non-alphanumerics, that's only the last character.

```
^\d.{4,10}[^a-z\d]$
```

Comment: You want 6-12 total characters. After you exclude the digit required at the beginning, and the non-alphanumeric at the end, that's 4-10 characters in the middle.